# How to send invoice mail automatically when invoice is created on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, customer, email, sales

What i tried to do, is to send invoice mail automatically to the customer when I successfully created an invoice.

By default the invoice mail in send just when i checked the `Email Copy Invoice` and then press Submit button(pictures)

[image]

I have a payment module(Buckaroo)  which create the invoice automatically for me, but the mail is not send.

So i want to create an observer to check everytime when an order is invoiced and send the mail automatically.

Does anyone know how can i do this? What event should I use for this?

Comment: Please ans this question also I have the same issue